# Web service authentication outside of webmethods body

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication

We have a web service in our company that we would like to publish for use for other developer teams. Still, we want to have a control over who uses it and if he is allowed to call this specific method or not.

Therefore we've come up with a solution to assign each team that wants to use our web service a key that tells which methods can be called by callers using this key. This key will be passed as a parameter to each method. Having this key as a parameter I can perform security check at the beginning of every method like this:

```
private bool CanCallMethod(string methodIdentifier, string authenticationKey)
{
  //check in db
}

public object GetLocation(string authenticationKey, int param1, string param2)
{
    if (!CanCallMethod(someMethodIdentifier, authenticationKey))
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    //method body
}

public object SetLocation(string authenticationKey, DateTime param1)
{
    if (!CanCallMethod(someOtherMethodIdentifier, authenticationKey))
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    //method body
}
```

But I have to do it in every method... And I have to remember about it in every new method and in every new web service. So the questions is:
**Is there any way I could design my class so that this check would be performed when any method is called without me every time explicitly invoking the check in method's body?**
Well I don't think so but it's always worth asking.

Comment: What type of web services? WCF? Restful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AOP with tool like PostSharp, Unity, or Castle to intercept or create a dynamic proxy.  This would likely force you to rework some of the services to implement an interface.  I only have experience with Unity, but implementing from an interface and then wiring them up with Aspects might work.

Maybe this can help too: [Best free way to use AOP style MVC-like authorization in business logic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081755/505893).